# Error in importing requests module in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I am using requests module in my python program. It worked great in the previous day. But now, when importing requests module, it is showing a weird error. It is working great in python2 version. But shows error in python3. I googled it but can't find a solution. I haven't changed anything. Why it is showing this error.

Here it is:

```
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 11, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 188, in <module>
    _verify_package_version(cryptography.__version__)
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 175, in _verify_package_version
    so_package_version = ffi.string(lib.CRYPTOGRAPHY_PACKAGE_VERSION)
AttributeError: cffi library '_openssl' has no function, constant or global variable named 'CRYPTOGRAPHY_PACKAGE_VERSION'
```

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clearer what your problem is.

Comment: Do you have both python 2 and 3 installed on the machine?

Comment: try: `pip3 uninstall cryptography` and `pip3 install cryptography>=2.1.1`

Comment: Thank u so much. The error got fixed....

Comment: try to install requests for python3: `pip3 install requests`. Anyway if you are going to use both 2.7 and 3.x its mandatory to use virtualenvs (for your mental health)

Comment: as @balderman suggested, try upgrading/downgrading cryptography to a specific version and see which is compatible with your use case

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling `cryptography` package will resolve this problem.